# Load dll from gac using Assembly.Load from remote machine?

Tags: .net, assemblies

How Load dll from gac using Assembly.Load from remote machine ?

Comment: Just to be clear, your assembly is gac'd where exactly?

Comment: seems to me, assembly is "gac'd" on machine A, and he wants to load it from machine B

Answer (score 0):

It can not be done.

The GAC is per machine only, unlike COM where you could use `CreateObject` on a different machine if the types were registered in both places.

Perhaps you should look into [WCF (Windows Communication Foundation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119.aspx) (This has replaced Remoting.)